# convert link into image

Tags: php, html, css

Simple question.

How can make this link become image?

Example:

```
<a href="updatecompany.php?companycode=<?php echo $r['code']; ?>"> Update </a>
```

**Update** <- It should be an image with title.

Comment: Where should the image come from? Are we talking about *every* `<a>` on a page or only certain ones?

Comment: In your editor, delete that line and type in `<img src="link/to/image" title="I should have figured this out" />`

Comment: path of image you want to use give an example

Comment: you want this link to be an image?

Comment: `<a ...><img src="update.png"></a>`

Comment: The text Update should be replaced with an image or you want an image with a link overtop of it? You can't convert a link to an image, they're two seperate things. Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: just add a image within the anchot tag `<a href="updatecompany.php?companycode=<?php echo $r['code']; ?>"> <img src= "......" title="title"/></a>`

Comment: If it is simple question, why are you asking here?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<a href="updatecompany.php?companycode=<?php echo $r['code']; ?>"> Update </a>
```

With

```
<a href="updatecompany.php?companycode=<?php echo $r['code']; ?>"> 
    <img src="/path/to/image.png" alt="Update" title="Update" /> 
</a>
```

Also, depending on what `$r['code']` contains, you may want to look into escaping and urlencoding to prevent [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Example:

```
<a href="updatecompany.php?companycode=<?php echo urlencode(htmlspecialchars($r['code'])); ?>"> 
    <img src="/path/to/image.png" alt="Update" title="Update" /> 
</a>
```

Comment: thanks mate, I'm grabbing 200 kilos of cholesterol just to solve this.,

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to link an image?

**WITH TITLE:**

```
<a href="updatecompany.php?companycode=<?php echo $r['code']; ?>">
 <img src="path/to/image" title="MY TITLE" alt="MY ALT"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="updatecompany.php?companycode=<?php echo $r['code']; ?>">
   <img src="your image path" alt=" your alt text" title="your title text" />
</a>
```

Comment: Any reason for that extra space in your alt?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href=updatecompany.php?companycode=<?php echo $r['code']; ?>" class="login" title="Login"><img src="../img/user.png"> />Update</a>


.login {
  background: url(../img/user.png) no-repeat 6px center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

}
```